# Value of <Span> that comes from javascript, how to put them in placeholder in html5?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript with name captcha.js

```js
function hasHtml5Validation () {
  return typeof document.createElement('input').checkValidity === 'function';
}

if (hasHtml5Validation()) {
  $('.validate-form').submit(function (e) {
    if (!this.checkValidity()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
      $('#status').html('invalid');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('invalid');
      $('#status').html('submitted');
    }
  });
}
//math to text function
function makenumber(numb){
if(numb==1)return "One";
if(numb==2)return "Two";
if(numb==3)return "Three";
if(numb==4)return "Four";
if(numb==5)return "Five";
if(numb==6)return "Six";
if(numb==7)return "Seven";
if(numb==8)return "Eight";
if(numb==9)return "Nine";
if(numb==10)return "Ten";
}//end makenumber function

function placenumber(){
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var no1 = makenumber(x);
var no2 = makenumber(y);
var ans = x+y;
document.getElementById('answer').pattern=ans;
document.getElementById("no1").innerHTML = no1;
document.getElementById("no2").innerHTML = no2;
}//end placenumber function
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="captcha.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple Captcha</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post">

<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  title="Are you human or bot ?" placeholder="" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script>placenumber();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here the value of javascript are go in html through innerhtml in a . I want to put that value in **placeholder** in html5 in a textbox. 
So how can I convert that  value in a variable and can put in placeholder.

Comment: are you looking for [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) function in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var Nothing = $("#myText").val();
  //JS: document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = Nothing;
  $("#myText").attr("placeholder", Nothing);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="No thing can do">
<button>DOEN NU</button>
```

Comment: Remove your text and there is your placeholder :)